# Point of tangency between a sphere and a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

I've got a bit of a problem. My problem is : on a sphere, show that if you have a quadrilateral from space tangent to it, the points of tangency (or the points of intersection between the sphere and the quadrilateral) are coplanar.

In the beginning, I thought there might be one, two, three or four points of tangency but a teacher told me that in this problem there must be four point of tangency. My teacher also told me that our problem can be decomposed in three problems : the main problem that I told you in the beginning and 2 special cases.

The first special case is if the quadrilateral is plane, the intersection between the quadrilateral and the sphere would be a circle. The second case is more difficult so I think I have to solve the other problems before.

To solve this problem, I have many ideas but I don't know how to do it and if it works. First I think that we can study if the lines who are passing through the points of tangency are secant at one moment. Am I wright ? Can it work ?

Next I used the equation of a sphere which I simplified by taking the radius equal to 1. I also used the fact that 4 points are coplanar if the vector
$$AD = n \vec{AB} + m\vec{AC}.$$
Then I put that expression according to $x(A)$, $y(A)$ and $z(A)$ and I put $ x(A)$, $y(A)$ and $z(A)$ in the equation of a sphere in
$$A : x(A)^2 + y(A)^2 + z(A)^2 = 1.$$
At the end I find that the equation of the sphere in $A$ depends of the equation of the sphere in $B, C$, and $D$ but I don't know what I can do with that. Moreover a friend told that with that I can find condition for $n$ and $m$, but I don't understand what that means.

Comment: Yes sorry, the points of tangeancy are the points on which every side of the quadrilateral are the connections between the sphere and the quadrilateral, the quadrilateral can only touch the sphere at these 4 points.

Comment: Dear Psensueur, this is a valid problem, and an interesting one too. Please improve the presentation, so it can be reopened.

Comment: But please, PSENSUEUR, don't play games with editing in an attempt to reopen, as orangeskid suggests.  You need far more context than you've provided. You've essentially copied a problem statement.  Please read [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Dear @orangeskid, it is not an interesting or valid question, unless the asker makes it so.  It's currently a run of the mill problem question statement.  Hence I provided the asker with information that can actually be used by the asker to improve the question.

Comment: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/3DQuadrilateral.shtml

Comment: You've made some progress in revising your Question, but the opening sentence ("on a sphere... you have a quadrilateral from space tangent to it") is unclear.  But your first Comment above is clear: each of four sides of the quadrilateral is tangent to that sphere.  The "big block of text" you wrote in the body of your Question is difficult to read.  Would you like my help in reformatting it and expressing that tangency condition clearly?

Comment: Yes I would like your help, HARDMATH.